# jQuery Mobile adds loading text I can't remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

When I include the **JS** file for the jQuery mobile features it adds a loading textual notice at the bottom of the page.

I have heard that you remove this by including the **CSS** for jQuery mobile, but this instead started changing all of the **CSS** for everything.

Is there a simple solution to this without seemingly themeing my web page to a jQuery mobile theme?

Comment: Find the element and hide it using css?

Comment: Open the `jQuery Mobile` CSS file and look for the bit related. Add it to your own CSS stylessheet.

Comment: to remove it completely use `$('.ui-loader').remove()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this:

Turn off loading spinner completely, by changing jQuery Mobile global settings after loading jQuery and before loading jQuery Mobile libraries.

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/Zn5eq/)**

```html
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>          
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
      $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
    });
  </script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The other way is to hide or remove the div containing the spinner `$('.ui-loader').hide()` or `.remove()`.

Answer (score 1):

The jquery script example didn't work for me and calling hide I feel is unnecessary. Plus, CSS is faster and you don't see that glitch of the loading showing up, then it disappears really fast. That just looks sloppy on a slow loading page. Just simply use CSS:

```
.ui-loader{
    display: none;
}
```